# use joomla com_media image selection in my custom component

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

hi 
i want to use com_media image selection in my own component. the link is:

```
index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=images&amp;tmpl=component&amp;
e_name=smallimage
```

the image goes to editor while i want it's address go to

```
<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="smallimage" id="smallimage" size="40" 
maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $row->smallimage; ?>" title=
"<?php echo JText::_('SMALLIMAGETIP' ); ?>" />
```

i am using joomla 1.5

any suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Joomla 1.6 the easy way is let Joomla do all the work for you. How?

First you need to include in you xml form (/model/forms/YOURFORM.xml) something like that...

```
<field name="imageurl" type="media" directory="CUSTOMDIRECTORY?"
                hide_none="1" label="COM_YOURCOMPONENT_IMG_LABEL"
                size="40"
                description="COM_YOURCOMPONENT_IMG_DESCRIPTION" />
```

Haven't you got a getForm() in your model?

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
    {

        // Get the form.
        try {
            //throw new Exception(JText::_('JLIB_FORM_ERROR_NO_DATA'));
            $form = $this->loadForm('com_kfiles', 'files');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "e";
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }

        if (empty($form)) {
            return false;
        }


        return $form;
    }
```

In your view (/views/xxxx/view.html.php) you need to load your form

```
$this->form = $this->get('Form');
```

Finally you only need to print the element in the template wherever you want.

```
echo $this->form->getLabel('imageurl'); 
echo $this->form->getInput('imageurl');
```

Bye

Comment: as I can see this type="media" is new in 1.6 and still not documented. http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_parameter_types I use the Banners Component as a Guide. Maybe you can use a Joomla Component as a guide if you know where the Image Picker is used.

Comment: image selector is used under editor input box and advanced editor use it, problem is that it send the picture to "text area" covered by img tag, while i want it to select address and bring it as string in my input box. i edited related js file but no result!

Comment: currently i'm working, if nobody answer til this afternoon I'll try to found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not straight forward, but you can have work around as mentioned here -
[Joomla Forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2253464)