# Use Media Manager as filepicker in component

Tags: joomla, components, filepicker, joomla1.6

I'm developing a component in Joomla 1.6, is a Document Manager and I have all the funcionality, but now I want to include the Media Manager as File Picker.

In Joomla 1.6 Media Manager is prepared to be use like a Image Picker (as we can see in the Article Manager where you can select a Image for the content), but I want to know if it's possible to reproduce the same action with all filetypes without modifying the Media Component.

I know how to use the media manager as Image Picker in my component. In fact I answered to this question.

[use joomla com_media image selection in my custom component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510904/use-joomla-com-media-image-selection-in-my-custom-component/5631950#5631950)

Can someone help me? :)

Byes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after the study of the component i got the fact that is not an easy question.

How can we use another filetypes?

`/administrator/components/com_media/models/list.php`

on line 116 exists a switch which works as a filter

If we want to add a new functionality (with a button)...

Where can we add the button?

`/administrator/components/com_media/views/images/tmpl/default.php`

Where can we add the javascript functionality?

`/media/media/js/popup-imagemanager.js`

Doing that we have some problems

1) we need to hardcode in every joomla.

2) I'm not sure, but the changes might be delete after a Joomla Updated.

Another chance is make a fork of the media component with theses changes ready to install.

Byes

Thanks to the tumbleweed badget to encourage me to write the response.